# Are there any landscape modes that are exclusive to the iPhone 6 and larger?

Tags: iphone

While playing with the iPhone 6 and 6+ I noticed that the 6+ has landscape features that the 6 doesn't. But I also noticed that the 6 and the 6+ have a landscape feature that the 5s doesn't which is pinch to zoom out and see all your tabs. Are there any other features like that?